# Evaluating strings and arrays - C

Tags: c, arrays, string

This is for C programming. I am studying for a midterm and one of the problems on the practice test had me a little confused and was hoping someone could help walk me through the code.

The code to the function is:

```
int xtoi(char s[])
{
    int i;
    int result;

    i = result = 0;
    while (s[i]) {
        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') {
            result = result * 16 + s[i++] - '0';
        } else if (s[i >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'f') {
            result = result * 16 + s[i++] - 'a' + 10;
        } else if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'F') {
            result = result * 16 + s[i++] - 'A' +10;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

What is the result of the following?

```
xtoi("1fa")
```

The answer should be `506`, but I have no idea how.  It is probably quite simple but this is all relatively new to me, so any help and guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is far too broad. If there's something *specific* you have a question about, you should narrow in on that.

Comment: Fire up a debugger and trace the program line by line. Watch all the local variables (better in hexadecimal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. - If `s[i]` is a `char` from '0' to '9', convert it to the
     corresponding `int`(0 to 9).
   - If not, if `s[i]` is a `char` from 'a' to 'f', convert it to the corresponding `int`(10 to 16).
   - If not, if `s[i]` is a `char` from 'A' to 'F', convert it to the corresponding `int`(10 to 16).
   - If still not, ignore it.
2. Then all such numbers are added up (following a rule) to generate the hex value represented by `s`.

Hint concerning the rule: For example, say you want to get a decimal number consists of '4' and '2'. You'll let a temporary result to be 4 first, multiply it by 10, and add 2 to that temp result. This will give you what you want: 4 * 10 + 2 = 42.

Please think about it again, and I promise you can understand it on your own.

---

BTW, the result of `xtoi("1fa")` is identical to that of `strtol("1fa", NULL, 16)`

Comment: Thanks guys, yea if feel quite stupid, figured it out after coming back to it with a clear head and realized it is simply a hex to decimal conversion.  Was using the Ascii numbers and that was way wrong, haha.

Answer (score 0):

The function converts hex strings into `int`s. It is analagous to `atoi`.

```
int xtoi(char s[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int result = 0;

    /* while we haven't seen the null terminator */
    while (s[i]) {
        /* if this char is a digit
         * convert this char to an int and then add
         * it to the next decimal place in the number.
         * Then advance to the next character */
        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
            result = result * 16 + s[i++] - '0';                   

        /* if this character is a hex digit
         * convert this char to an int and then add 
         * it to the next decimal place in the number.
         * Then advance to the next character */
        else if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'f')
            result = result * 16 + s[i++] - 'a' + 10;

        /* same as above, except for uppercase hex digits */
        else if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'F')
            result = result * 16 + s[i++] - 'A' + 10;
    }
    /* return the converted number */
    return result;
}
```

This program could be rewritten like this

```
int xtoi(char s[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int result = 0;

    /* while we haven't seen the null terminator */
    for (i = 0; s[i]; ++i) {
        /* if this char is a digit
         * convert this char to an int and then add
         * it to the next decimal place in the number. */
        if (isdigit(s[i]))
            result = result * 16 + (s[i] - '0');

        /* if this character is a hex digit
         * convert this char to an int and then add
         * it to the next decimal place in the number. */
        else if (isxdigit(s[i])) {
            /* if the hex digit is uppercase, the char to subtract
             * from is also uppercase. Otherwise it is lowercase */
            char base = isupper(s[i]) ? 'A' : 'a';
            result = result * 16 + s[i] - base + 10;
        }
    }
    /* return the converted number */
    return result;
}
```

The output of the new `xtoi("1fa");` is correct: 506.